# HTML and Javascript: How to append paragraph element that contains user input into a div element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple webpage as a test to see if I can put text inputted by the user (using textarea) and add it using a button. This button is meant to create a new paragraph element, have that user input inside of it, and append that paragraph to a div element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>
        function insert_text () {
            var para = document.createElement('p');
            var node = document.createTextNode('This is new.');
            para.appendChild(node);
            
            var element = document.getElementById('content_body');
            element.appendChild(para);
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <fieldset>
            Text to insert: <br/>
            <textarea id="content" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
            <button id="add" onclick="insert_text()">Add</button>
        <fieldset>

        <div id="content_body">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Currently, I can only manage to append a pre-made text node as seen with `var node = document.createTextNode('This is new.');` When I want to make changes to my function so it instead grabs the user input, this is what the `insert_text()` function becomes:

```js
function insert_text () {
            var para = document.createElement('p');
            var node = document.getElementById('content').value;
            para.appendChild(node);
            
            var element = document.getElementById('content_body');
            element.appendChild(para);
        }
```

But when I do this, nothing ends up being appended to the div element... What seems to be my issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your second insert_text function, your `var node` is not a DOM element but a string. It is the text inside your `content` textarea, but that text alone does not constitute an HTML element.

Using a textnode like in your example, you can create and initialize the text node using the string content of your textarea. That way you get a node whose text value is what you wanted.

```
 var para = document.createElement('p');
 var node = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("content").value);
 para.appendChild(node);
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my issue!

Comment: @hacker_man_2021 Please avoid to add a comment on an answer to say "Thank you". You can better vote or accept the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)